# Windows not clearing after closed - Kubuntu 21.10

Tags: nvidia, kubuntu, screen, desktop-environments, 21.10

I'm facing the following problem. Sometimes an application window does not clear and remains stuck in the foreground. In a short time, the entire screen is filled with images of closed applications, but still on the screen. It is not possible to work and I have to log out.
Details: I'm running Kubuntu 21.10, fresh installation with Kubuntu backports from the PPA. The graphics card is an old nvidia with nouveau drivers.
Everything was fine with Kubuntu 20.04 :( Like they say "don't fix, it if it's not broken".
I'm a strong linux fan, but not a developer.
I need a good advice, please. TIA